# Loop to print text files is skipping some files(randomly, it seems)

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET program which lists some text files in a directory and loops through them. For each file, the program calls notepad.exe with the /p parameter and the filename to print the file, then copies the file to a history directory, sleeps for 5 seconds(to allow notepad to open and print), and finally deletes the original file.

What's happening is, instead of printing every single text file, it is only printing "random" files from the directory. Every single text file gets copied to the history directory and deleted from the original however, so I know that it is definitely listing all of the files and attempting to process each one. I've tried adding a call to Thread.Sleep for 5000 milliseconds, then changed it to 10000 milliseconds to be sure that the original file wasn't getting deleted before notepad grabbed it to print.

I'm more curious about what is actually happening than anything (a fix would be nice too!). I manually moved some of the files that did not print to the original directory, removing them from the history directory, and reran the program, where they DID print as they should, so I know it shouldn't be the files themselves, but something to do with the code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim f() As String = ListFiles("l:\", "997")
    Dim i As Integer
    Try
        For i = 0 To f.Length - 1
            If Not f(i) = "" Then
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe", " /p l:\" & f(i))
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("l:\" & f(i), "k:\" & f(i))
                'Thread.Sleep(5000)
                Thread.Sleep(10000)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("l:\" & f(i))
            End If
        Next
        'Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Thread.Sleep(10000)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function ListFiles(ByVal strFilePath As String, ByVal strFileFilter As String) As String()
    'finds all files in the strFilePath variable and matches them to the strFileFilter variable
    'adds to string array strFiles if filename matches filter
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFiles(0) As String
    Dim strExclude As String = ""
    Dim pos As Integer = 0
    Dim posinc As Integer = 0

    strFileName = Dir(strFilePath)
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        'check to see if filename matches filter
        If InStr(strFileName, strFileFilter) Then
            If InStr(strFileName, "997") Then
                FileOpen(1, strFilePath & strFileName, OpenMode.Input)
                Do Until EOF(1)
                    strExclude = InputString(1, LOF(1))
                Loop
                pos = InStr(UCase(strExclude), "MANIFEST")
                posinc = posinc + pos
                pos = InStr(UCase(strExclude), "INVOICE")
                posinc = posinc + pos
                FileClose(1)
            Else : posinc = 1
            End If
            If posinc > 0 Then
                'add file to array
                ReDim Preserve strFiles(i)
                strFiles(i) = strFileName
                i += 1
            Else
                My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile("l:\" & strFileName, "k:\" & strFileName)
            End If
            'MsgBox(strFileName & " " & IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFileName).ToString)
            pos = 0
            posinc = 0
        End If
        'get the next file
        strFileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Return strFiles
End Function
```

Brief overview of the code above. An automated program fills the "L:\" directory with text files, and this program needs to print out certain files with "997" in the filename (namely files with "997" in the filename and containing the text "INVOICE" or "MANIFEST"). The ListFiles function does exactly this, then back in the Form1_Load() sub it is supposed to print each file, copy it, and delete the original.

Something to note, this code is developed in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7. The machine that actually runs this program is still on Windows XP.

Comment: What's the Sleep accomplishing?  ListFiles looks like it's doing more than just returning a list. That's a bad smell.

Comment: Without the Sleep, the call to Notepad would error because the original file would be copied and deleted by the time Notepad went to send it to the printer. ListFiles puts the file contents into a string, and checks to see if it contains "MANIFEST" or "INVOICE". If it does, it adds the filename to the string array, otherwise it moves the file(because it doesn't need to be printed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few issues.  the first and most obvious is the error handling:

You have a Try.. Catch with no error handling.  You may be running in to an error without knowing it!!  Add some output here, so you know if that is the case.

The second issue is to do with the way you are handling Process classes.

Instead of just calling System.Diagnostics.Process.Start in a loop and sleeping you should use the inbuilt method of handling execution.  You are also not disposing of anything, which makes me die a little inside.

Try something like

```
    Using p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        p.Start("Notepad.exe", " /p l:\" & f(i))
        p.WaitForExit()
    End Using
```

With both of these changes in place you should not have any issues.  If you do there should at least be errors for you to look at and provide here, if necessary.

Comment: I will try that and let you know the results. Yes, I know about the error handling...I'm not sure why it was originally coded with nothing in the Catch statement, and while staring at this trying to figure out what's missing I didn't even catch that. Thank you!

Comment: I removed the Sleep call and replaced the call to Notepad with the code you posted...so far so good! It's a little hard to tell because it doesn't always skip printing files, but if it continues to do so down the road I will post back. Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds promising.  Keep me posted :)